# Need to find the all nearby node elements for every node on the graph using PHP

Tags: php

**Problem**

Need to find the all nearby node elements for every node on the following graph using PHP

[Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xRcqR.png)

**Input String**

```
$string_arr = array (‘c1#c2#6’, ‘c2#c3#12’, ‘c2#c4#3’, ‘c3#c5#22’, ‘c3#c6#23’, ‘c4#c7#13’, ‘c5#c8#16’, ‘c6#c8#11’, ‘c6#c9#9’, ‘c7#c9#12’, ‘c9#c10#15’, ‘c8#c10#7’);
```

(Use above variable as input parameter for your code. And you can treat it as string or array or array of string)

**Required OUTPUT:**

Please print the array showing all node elements with their nearby node.
e.g.

```
Array(
[c1] => Array
(
    [0] => c2
)

[c2] => Array
(
    [0] => c1
    [1] => c3
    [2] => c4
)
)
```

**My Code**

```
   <?php

$string_arr = array('c1#c2#6', 'c2#c3#12', 'c2#c4#3', 'c3#c5#22', 'c3#c6#23', 'c4#c7#13', 'c5#c8#16', 'c6#c8#11', 'c6#c9#9',
    'c7#c9#12', 'c9#c10#15', 'c8#c10#7');
foreach ($string_arr as $k => $v) {
    $tmp = explode('#', $v);
    $new_array[$tmp[0]][] = $tmp[1];
    #$new_array2[$tmp[0]][] = $tmp[2];
}



print_r($new_array);

?>
```

**My Output**

```
 Array (
     [c1] => Array
         (
             [0] => c2
         )

     [c2] => Array
         (
             [0] => c3
             [1] => c4
         )

     [c3] => Array
         (
             [0] => c5
             [1] => c6
         )

     [c4] => Array
         (
             [0] => c7
         )

     [c5] => Array
         (
             [0] => c8
         )

     [c6] => Array
         (
             [0] => c8
             [1] => c9
         )

     [c7] => Array
         (
             [0] => c9
         )

     [c9] => Array
         (
             [0] => c10
         )

     [c8] => Array
         (
             [0] => c10
         )

 )
```

Answer (score 1):

I think all you need to do is also add the items in the other way round, so you currently add...

```
$new_array[$tmp[0]][] = $tmp[1];
```

so also add with the values swapped

```
$new_array[$tmp[1]][] = $tmp[0];
```

To give...

```
foreach ($string_arr as $k => $v) {
    $tmp = explode('#', $v);
    $new_array[$tmp[0]][] = $tmp[1];
    $new_array[$tmp[1]][] = $tmp[0];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$string_arr  = array ('c1#c2#6', 'c2#c3#12', 'c2#c4#3', 'c3#c5#22', 'c3#c6#23', 'c4#c7#13', 'c5#c8#16', 'c6#c8#11', 'c6#c9#9', 'c7#c9#12', 'c9#c10#15', 'c8#c10#7');

$simplifyArr = array();

foreach ($string_arr  as $key => $value) {
    $simplifyArr[] = getnode($value);
}

$keysArr = array_unique(array_column($simplifyArr, 'parent'));


$outputArr = array();
foreach ($keysArr as $key) {
    foreach ($simplifyArr as $value) {
        if($value['parent'] == $key){
            $outputArr[$key][] = $value['child'];
        }

        if($value['child'] == $key){
            $outputArr[$key][] = $value['parent'];
        }
    }
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($outputArr);
echo "</pre>";

function getnode($string)
{
    $extract = explode('#', $string);

    $arr['parent'] = $extract[0];
    $arr['child'] = $extract[1];
    $arr['weight'] = $extract[2];

    return $arr;
}
?>
```